# java8 method reference , allowing incompatiable return type

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-interface

This is regarding method reference call, in lambda we are able to make method reference to methods having different return type. See below code -

```
interface Sayable {
    void say();
}

class SayableImpl implements Sayable {

    @Override
    public boolean say() {
        // error wrong return type
    }
}

public class MethodReference {
    public static boolean saySomething() {
        System.out.println("Hello, this is static method.");
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MethodReference methodReference = new MethodReference();
        Sayable sayable = () -> methodReference.saySomething();
        sayable.say();

        // Referring static method
        Sayable sayable2 = MethodReference::saySomething;
        sayable2.say();
    }
}
```

Here we are implementing void `say()` method with `MethodReference::saySomething()`, whose return type is `boolean`.

How do we justify it? Am I missing something?

Comment: but if you are trying to implement it with different return type, compiler complains. Does that means there is a some change of rule if we use lamda for implementation?

Comment: Interestingly this is true for void return types only, non void return types (of say() method) triggers compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

Because you can also write

```
class SayableImpl implements Sayable {
    @Override
    public void say() {
        new MethodReference().saySomething();
    }
}
```

which is what you eventually end up doing while representing it using the lambda

```
Sayable sayable = () -> methodReference.saySomething()
```

Comment: thanks, but above implementation will show compilation error- 'Void method cannot return a value'.    please check.

Comment: @vinod notice, I didn't add a `return` in the code and hence it should compile successfully.